# Using a bash script positional parameter to point to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, parameters

I'm trying to make a simple script to switch GCP Projects with GCLOUD in a similar vein to KUBECTX\NS does with KUBECTL.

Thus, simply to take a positional script parameter ($1) value to access the project-id value from a predefined variable.

so executing such as: > `sh gcp-proj.sh dev`

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash    
DEV="google-project-dev"
TEST="google-project-test"
gcloud config set [this would be one of the above values, but using the variable name referenced from $1]
```

How do I map $1 (dev) to the DEV variable and put the variable value into the above placeholder?

Comment: The target i'm trying to achieve is:

user parameter can be:  dev, test, prod
the script will have variables of dev, test, prod with values such as "gcp-project-dev", "gcp-project-test", "gcp-project-prod" respectively.

Thus, when the user inputs "dev", the $1 parameter will match to the variable name and obtain the value of "gcp-project-dev" and populate into the command "gcloud config set gcp-project-dev".

Whilst useful for other use cases, I don't believe the answer below reflects that functionality.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following your placeholder, this would look like this

```bash
#!/bin/bash

DEV=${1:-google-project-dev}
gcloud config set $DEV
```

i.e: first argument or `google-project-dev`

Comment: Should than not be `set $DEV` ?

Comment: @Zak Good catch. You are right.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't want to be able to use the actual first argument of the command line (so "dev" would not be a valid project name, but you substitute "dev" with the value in the "dev" variable when executing the `gcloud` command.
Futhermore, $DEV could point to any of the other variables; in the example TEST.